# How to compare a Class<*> against a Java boxed primitive type without kotlin compiler warnings

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin to write something that works with Java's reflection APIs. My input is a `Class<*>` and I need to decide whether that type is a double or integer, but I need to support both primitives *and* the boxed nullable types that Java uses.

This toy example does what I'm trying to do:

```
when(type) {
    java.lang.Double::class.java, Double::class.java -> TypesEnum.DOUBLE
    java.lang.Integer::class.java, Int::class.java   -> TypesEnum.INT
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("type")
}
```

But, this approach generates the following warnings from the Kotlin compiler:

> Warning:(22, 13) Kotlin: This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use kotlin.Double instead.
>   Warning:(23, 13) Kotlin: This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use kotlin.Int instead.

However, `Int?::class.java` is a syntax error, [the approaches suggested on an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946044/kotlin-reflection-check-nullable-types) require a `KClass` instead of a `Class<*>` (and the [`.kotlin` extension method](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMapping.kt#L86) crashes on some of my inputs). What's the correct Kotlin way to perform this kind of check?

---

**Edit:** Further investigation (prompted by @voddan's answer) has revealed that this problem is a symptom of a more general bit of weirdness in Kotlin's type reflection:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // ::class.java of Kotlin's own Double type is just double
    println(Double::class)                            // -> class kotlin.Double
    println(Double::class.java)                       // -> double

    // But starting from Java's nullable java.lang.Double gives an entirely different result
    println(java.lang.Double::class)                  // -> class kotlin.Double
    println(java.lang.Double::class.java)             // -> class java.lang.Double
    println(java.lang.Double::class.java.kotlin)      // -> class kotlin.Double
    println(java.lang.Double::class.java.kotlin.java) // -> class java.lang.Double

    // Suggested by @mfulton26; works.
    println(Class.forName("java.lang.Double"))        // -> class java.lang.Double
}
```

So it seems not all `class kotlin.Double`s are created equal. I've played with casts and aux variables and the results seem highly consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [`Class.kotlin`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.lang.-class/kotlin.html) should work. If it "crashes on some of [your] inputs" then I recommend filing an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).
2. You can use [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)). to avoid the compiler warnings. e.g. `Class.forName("java.lang.Integer")`.
3. You can [suppress](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-suppress/) the warning.
4. You can use [`KClass.javaObjectType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html) and [`KClass.javaPrimitiveType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-primitive-type.html):

   ```
   when (type) {
       Double::class.javaObjectType, Double::class.javaPrimitiveType -> TypesEnum.DOUBLE
       Int::class.javaObjectType, Int::class.javaPrimitiveType -> TypesEnum.INT
       else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("type")
   }
   ```

Comment: `Class.kotlin` works on try.kotlinlang.org but not my system, so this is clearly the right answer and my environment is messed up.

Comment: `Class.forName("java.lang.Double").kotlin` matches `Double::class` in a when block, but only on kotlin 1.0.4 and above. I had an old version.

Answer (score 1):

`Int?` is not a class, but a type, meaning that a reference of this type is ether `int`, `Integer` or `null`.

`Int::class.java` should give you `java.lang.Integer` I think.

I can't check it right now, but IMO converting `Class` to `KClass` is your best option:

```
when(type.kotlinClass) {
    Double::class -> TypesEnum.DOUBLE
    Int::class   -> TypesEnum.INT
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("type")
}
```

Comment: `Int::class.java` is just `int`, not `java.lang.Integer`. Edited question with more experimentation.

Comment: Yes, but `type.kotlin` should return `Int` no matter what was the original type