# Check type of member/property

Tags: reflection, types, kotlin

Let's say i have any class, like this one:

```
class SomeClass(val aThing: String, val otherThing: Double)
```

Then I use reflection to analyze the fields of this class:

```
for(field in SomeClass.declaredMemberProperties){

}
```

How can I check the type of each field?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Kotlin does not have fields but only properties with backing fields, you should check the return type of the property.

Try this:

```
    class SomeClass(val aThing: String, val otherThing: Double)

    for(property in SomeClass::class.declaredMemberProperties) {
        println("${property.name} ${property.returnType}")
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

If the class does not use custom getters and/or setters without backing fields, you can get the type of the backing field like this:

```
property.javaField?.type
```

As a complete example, here is your class with an additional val property called foo with a custom getter (so no backing field is created). You will see that getJavaField() of that property will return null.

```
    class SomeClass(val aThing: String, val otherThing: Double) {
        val foo : String
            get() = "foo"
    }

    for(property in SomeClass::class.declaredMemberProperties) {
        println("${property.name} ${property.returnType} ${property.javaField?.type}")
    }
```

**UPDATE2:**

Using `String::class.createType()` will return the KType for every KClass, so you can use e.g. `property.returnType == String::class.createType()` to find out if it's a (kotlin) String.

Comment: That's a progress. property.returnType returns me a KType. How can I check, for example if I want to check it againist a String, if that KType is a String, or get the String KType? 'is' doesn't work, equals neither.

Comment: Instead of using `createType()`, you can use `property.returnType.classifier as? KClass`.

Comment: @AllanAraújo you or others have read this might encounter interesting use case for nullable properties inside your data class. 

Since the KType parameter will return not-nullable type, you have to this:


1. `property.type == Any::class.[createType()|startProjectedType].withNullability(true)`


_**Ref**:_ [nullable KType](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/getting-the-ktype-of-a-nullable-type/2220), or [Build custom method nullable check for ur data class or use javaType](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35946841/3763032)